# Libgdx - How to use android ShareCompact or shareActionProvider in lingdx

Tags: android, libgdx

Hi I am new to LibGdx and android, i need to use ShareCompact to share text via email or WhatsApps. I searched but find to way how to do this. I added

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
```

and in the java

```
   import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;
```

I am getting error message- "Can not resolve symbol ShareCompact"
I searched net but found no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShareCompact` class is inside support-compat artifact.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

If you're using AndroidX build artifact than ShareCompact is in `androidx.core:core:1.0.0` library

---

I've never used `ShareCompact` in LibGDX but I think through [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) you can use.